# Windows service hosting a WCF service closing immediately

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I tried hosting a WCF Library service with windows service project, I installed the service, however, when i start the service in services.msc, the service start and closses immediatly.  Following the message that gets displayed:

> The Servicel service on Local
>   Computer started and then stopped.
>   Some services stop automatically if
>   they are not in use by other services
>   or programs.

The `App.config` file for wcf and the windows service project is same and it is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WorkMateWCF.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WorkMateWCF.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/WorkMate1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

The entire project/solution is downloadable here: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=d358d316fa2c3a37&sc=documents&uc=1&id=D358D316FA2C3A37%21135#

Could you please guide me on how to proceed further.  Thank you.

Additional information:
Following is the code from the service1.cs file in windows service project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WorkMateWCF;

namespace WorkMateWinService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        internal static ServiceHost MyServiceHost = null;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (MyServiceHost != null)
            {
                MyServiceHost.Close();
            }
            MyServiceHost=new ServiceHost(typeof( Service1));
            MyServiceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (MyServiceHost != null)
            {
                MyServiceHost.Close();
                MyServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more info concerning this problem in your post, rather than relying on a downloadable project. The question and its answers are supposed to be beneficial for all.

Comment: could you please tell me what more information is needed, becuase i think i mentioned the problem, I am new to coding, please let me know what more information is required.  Thank you.

Comment: A good start would be to show the code in the service's Start method. Any other information that can be relevant is welcome.

Comment: Thanks Roy Dictus, I have added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue, when I reviewed my event logs I found this:

```
"Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.EnsureGetDispatcher(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceMetadataExtension mex, Uri url, String scheme)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.CreateHttpGetEndpoints(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase host, ServiceMetadataExtension mex)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.ApplyBehavior(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase host)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescript..."
```

Then after thorough reviewing, the issues is that I did HTTPSGETENABLED to false only for one, infact there are two, after making the change for the other one, the app started to work like charm.

I special

Answer (score 1):

What I find very confusing (and probably the .NET runtime, too) is the fact that your Windows Service is called `Service1`, while your WCF Service **also** is called `Service1` (without a namespace or anything).

So which of the two `Service1` class types will be used here???

```
MyServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
```

I'm not sure - and I'm afraid it will be the **wrong** class (the Windows NT Service class).

You should give your stuff more meaningful names and keep those things apart (by name, too) !

Comment: Thanks marc_s, I want the wcf to run in this case.  Could you please tell me on how to do that change.  Thanks a lot for making me understand the mistake.  I tried to do it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx and I am not so good at c#

Comment: @surpavan: just rename the WCF service class to `MyWCFService` and then use `MyServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCFService));`. This way, you have two distinct names - `Service1` is your host, the NT Service, while `MyWCFService` is the WCF service (as the name implies)

Comment: I am very sorry to say this that I am unable to do that thing, it is pretty confusing for me, could you please make that change and give me the file/files so that I can compare and understand where or what it is.   Thanks for everything till now.

Comment: @surpavan: did you see the note in the source file? `NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.` - can you do this??

Comment: sorry marc_s, still the same problem, could you please do the required modifications and attach the file.  What i have done is in the service project, I refactor>Renamed the "Service1 : ServiceBase" class name to "TService1 : ServiceBase" but same error still exists.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have uploaded the edited files, could you please check once more and try if the service is running on your PC, Thanks for all you precious time.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=d358d316fa2c3a37&sc=documents&uc=1&id=D358D316FA2C3A37%21135#